# Playing audio over bluetooth from some sources mutes others

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones

When I play audio through bluetooth headphones, the following happens:

- Play the Google timer in Chrome or playback from Logic Pro X. Works fine.
- Play a YouTube video or Spotify song. Stop it.
- Go back to Google time or Logic Pro. Now there's no sound.
- YouTube and Spotify have no issue, I can play one first then the other.

When I'm playing over the computer speakers this does not occur. I can go back and forth between YouTube/Spotify and Logic/timer.

Thank you for your help. I'm on Big Sur 11.2.3 but I've faced this issue over multiple OS versions.